# Can I plug a cisco phone directly into raspbx ethernet port

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, asterisk, ethernet, cisco

Can I plug a cisco SPA303 ip phone directly into the ethernet port of a raspberry pi running raspbx?

I have got raspbx setup and running using a wifi dongle to connect to the router. The system works with the Cisco phone plugged into the router. However, the router is on the other-side of my house and ideally, as the raspbx is wifi, I would like to plug the phone directly into the pi and have it as one unit I can have anywhere in the house.

I have spent a painful amount of hours trying to set this up and I am sure there is a simple fix I am overlooking. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you should setup static ip on phone or setup dhcpd server on RPi

Also some cisco phones have double ports(internal simpler switch inside). If so, you can connect one-by-one upto 8 phones.

Answer (score 0):

There are several layers to take into consideration:

- Link layer MDI/MDI-X detection of crossover/patch ethernet cable detection.
- Static IP address for Raspberry Pi and a DHCP server for the IP phone
- TFTP server to provisionize the IP phone
- A peer in asterisk for the IP phone